# how to get count in numberOfRowsInSection from Array in nested Decodable Model

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

```
struct myOrdesItems: Decodable {

    let userFName: String?
    let userLName: String?
    let userOrderPreSerial: String?
    let userOrderSerial: Int?
    let userOrderProductsValue: Int?
    let userOrderOrderedDate: String?
    let payTypeDescEN: String?
    let listUserOrderStatus : [listUserOrderStatus]
    let listUserOrderShipmentVM: [listUserOrderShipmentVM]

}

struct listUserOrderStatus: Decodable {
    let userOrderStatusTitleEN: String?
    let userOrderStatusID: Int?
}

struct listUserOrderShipmentVM: Decodable {
    let userOrderStatusTimeLine: [userOrderStatusTimeLine]
}


struct userOrderStatusTimeLine: Decodable {
    let userOrderStatusID: Int?
}


var myorderArray : [myOrdesItems] = []

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView.tag == 10 {
        return myorderArray.count
    } else {
        for number in 0..<(myorderArray.count) {
            let value = myorderArray[number].listUserOrderShipmentVM.count

            print(value)
            arrayOfElement.append(value)
        }

        return arrayOfElement.count
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post the question only in the title, add it to the actual question as well and also clarify what is the issue with your current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what You are asking for

```
 if tableView.tag == 10 {
        return myorderArray.count
 } else {
    return  myorderArray.flatMap{$0.userOrderShipmentVMArray}.count;
}
```

EDIT

Change

```
 let listUserOrderShipmentVM: [listUserOrderShipmentVM]
```

to

```
 let userOrderShipmentVMArray: [listUserOrderShipmentVM]
```